# On tag mouse over stop animation for jQuery Tag Cloud

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to make [jQuery 3D tag cloud](http://plugins.jquery.com/tagcloud/) on tag mouse over (hover) stop animation (rotation)?

Answer (score 0):

As I see from the code: https://github.com/dynamicguy/tagcloud/blob/master/src/tagcloud.jquery.js the answer is **no.**

All options are encapsulated in the plugin's scope, which cannot be accessed from outside. You would have to modify the code in order to be able to manipulate the "speed" property.

Then you could just set the speed to "0" on mouse enter and back to the original speed on mouse leave.

Comment: or you could just edit line 154 to if (false), so it will ignore mouse-over right away. https://github.com/dynamicguy/tagcloud/blob/master/src/tagcloud.jquery.js#L154